# Adding event listener in angularjs factory method is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For reasons I would not go into here, I am adding an event listner in the factory method(**serviceAFunction**) as against controller. When I click the call chain fails subsequently. I get `"Uncaught TypeError: this.serviceC is not a function"` in the browser console. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried Prototype approach as well as shown in the next snippet, but no luck again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
          'use strict';
          function myFactory($http) {
              var service = {
                  serviceA: serviceAFunction,
                  serviceB: serviceBFunction,
                  serviceC: serviceCFunction,
                  serviceD: serviceDFunction,
                  callParams: {}
              };
              return service;
              function serviceAFunction() {
                  alert("From A service");
                  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", this.serviceB);
                  //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () { alert(1);});
                  //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", $scope.doSomeThing);
                  this.serviceB();
              }
              function serviceBFunction() {
                  alert("From B service");
                  // During click event the following call fails.
                  this.serviceC();
              }
              function serviceCFunction() {
                  alert("From C service");
                  this.serviceD();
              }
              function serviceDFunction() {
                  alert("From D service");
              }
          }
          function myController($scope, $controller, myFactory) {
              $scope.doSomeThing = function () {
                  myFactory.serviceA();
              };
              myFactory.serviceA();
          }
          angular.module('myApp', []);
          angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', myFactory);
          myFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
          angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
          myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller', 'myFactory'];

      }())
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>Here we go...</h1>
    <div id='MyTrial'>
      <input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Click Me"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Prototype Approach. No success here as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
          'use strict';
          function myFactory() {
              function Factory($scope) {
                  this.$scope = $scope;
              }
              Factory.prototype.serviceA = serviceAFunction;
              Factory.prototype.serviceB = serviceBFunction;
              Factory.prototype.serviceC = serviceCFunction;
              Factory.prototype.serviceD = serviceDFunction;
              return Factory;
              function serviceAFunction() {
                  alert("From A service");
                  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", this.$scope.newFactory.serviceB);
                  //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () { alert(1);});
                  //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", $scope.doSomeThing);
                  this.serviceB();
              }
              function serviceBFunction() {
                  alert("From B service");
                  // What ever I do here, during click event the following call fails.
                  this.$scope.newFactory.serviceC();
              }
              function serviceCFunction() {
                  alert("From C service");
                  this.$scope.newFactory.serviceD();
              }
              function serviceDFunction() {
                  alert("From D service");
              }
          }
          function myController($scope, $controller, myFactory) {

              $scope.doSomeThing = function () {
                  //myFactory.serviceA();
              };
              $scope.newFactory = new myFactory($scope);
              $scope.newFactory.serviceA();
          }
          angular.module('myApp', []);
          angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', myFactory);
          //myFactory.$inject = ['$scope'];
          angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
          myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller', 'myFactory'];
      }())
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>Here we go...</h1>
    <div id='MyTrial'>
      <input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Click Me"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a javascript issue.

You must cache the parent scope like so:

```
var self = this;
function serviceBFunction() {
    alert("From B service");
    // During click event the following call fails.
    self.serviceC();
}
```

Comment: :(. I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceC' of undefined

Comment: I mean, in your case the `this` are the `service` variable

Comment: Wow...It seems to work!!. Can you please elaborate, what this trick is called? And is there a way the second Prototype approach can be made to work.

Comment: Well, is not even a pattern but a technique for isolating scope context when needed, is commonly used with closure or any scope chain when is necessary refer to the parent scope.

Comment: Anyway , about the second prototype it can't be done because `$scope` is for controllers, is not a service to be injected in a factory.

Comment: So, can please provide me with a few links so I may read further. I marked this as the answer by the way.

Comment: Well, there is a lot of stuff but I think this one is a good choice http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: I made it to work after I replaced this. with service. in the factory methods. That is, I did two changes. First, I added var service = this;. Next I had changed this.serviceB(); to service.serviceB(); and this.serviceC(); to service.serviceC(); and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing jquery onclick functionality in Factory? Is there any necessary.

If you want call serviceB from button click, then call this method through the controller.

> When you use jquery onclick, then here this will be act as element
>   that is you are actually trying to do $(element). So this will not have the collection of methods/variable where the angular factories will hold.
>
> But in Angular scenario, this is different. Since you need scope or
>   factory functions desperately, then do your code logic in factory
>   instead of jquery onclick functionalities.

```html
<head>
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
          'use strict';
          function myFactory($http) {
              var service = {
                  serviceA: serviceAFunction,
                  serviceB: serviceBFunction,
                  serviceC: serviceCFunction,
                  serviceD: serviceDFunction,
                  callParams: {}
              };
              return service;
              function serviceAFunction() {
                  alert("From A service");
                
                 // document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", this.serviceB);
                  //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () { alert(1);});
                  //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", $scope.doSomeThing);
                  this.serviceB();
              }
              function serviceBFunction() {
                  alert("From B service");
                  // During click event the following call fails.
                  this.serviceC();
              }
              function serviceCFunction() {
                  alert("From C service");
                  this.serviceD();
              }
              function serviceDFunction() {
                  alert("From D service");
              }
          }
          function myController($scope, $controller, myFactory) {
              $scope.doSomeThing = function () {
                  myFactory.serviceB();
              };
              myFactory.serviceA();
          }
          angular.module('myApp', []);
          angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', myFactory);
          myFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
          angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
          myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller', 'myFactory'];

      }())
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>Here we go...</h1>
    <div id='MyTrial'>
      <input id="myBtn" type="button" ng-click="doSomeThing()" value="Click Me"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: In the application I use d3(d3js.org) and in one of the factory methods it adds some event handlers. So what I have shown here is a stripped down version. I have already tried what you have suggested, and thats not what I want.